# How to make a overlap table from multiple lists/vectors in R?

Tags: r, overlap

I have multiple lists of genes, for example:

`listA <- c("geneA", "geneB", "geneC")`

`listB <- c("geneA", "geneB", "geneD", "geneE")`

`listC <- c("geneB", "geneF")`

```
...
```

I'd like to get a table to show the # of overlapping elements between the lists, like:

```
       listA   listB  listC  ...
listA   3       2      1
listB   2       4      1
listC   1       1      2
...
```

I know how to get the # of overlaps between each pair, like `length(intersect(listA, listB))`. But what are the easier ways to generate the overlap table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way in `base R`

```
crossprod(table(stack(mget(ls(pattern = "^list")))))
#       ind
#ind     listA listB listC
#  listA     3     2     1
#  listB     2     4     1
#  listC     1     1     2
```

`mget(ls(pattern = "^list"))` will give you a list of elements from your global environment whose names begin with "list".

`stack` will turn this list into the following data frame

```
stack(mget(ls(pattern = "^list")))
#  values   ind
#1  geneA listA
#2  geneB listA
#3  geneC listA
#4  geneA listB
#5  geneB listB
#6  geneD listB
#7  geneE listB
#8  geneB listC
#9  geneF listC
```

Calling  `table` returns.

```
out <- table(stack(mget(ls(pattern = "^list"))))
out
#       ind
#values  listA listB listC
#  geneA     1     1     0
#  geneB     1     1     1
#  geneC     1     0     0
#  geneD     0     1     0
#  geneE     0     1     0
#  geneF     0     0     1
```

`crossprod` then calculates

```
t(out) %*% out
```

which returns

```
#       ind
#ind     listA listB listC
#  listA     3     2     1
#  listB     2     4     1
#  listC     1     1     2
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a list of all objects

```
list.all <- list(listA, listB, listC)
```

use `outer`

```
outer(list.all, list.all, Vectorize(function(x, y) sum(x %in% y)))

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    3    2    1
# [2,]    2    4    1
# [3,]    1    1    2
```

or use `sapply`

```
sapply(list.all, function(x) sapply(list.all, function(y) sum(y %in% x)))

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    3    2    1
# [2,]    2    4    1
# [3,]    1    1    2
```

Comment: what does Vectorize do?

Comment: It's a wrapper for `mapply`. For example, `vrep <- Vectorize(rep.int);
vrep(1:4, 4:1)` is the same as 
`mapply(rep.int, 1:4, 4:1)`